# How do I make my UIButton title have some padding?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

Let's say I have a UIButton with a size of 120 wide by 30 high. I set an attributed title on it with centered text and I set a background color on the text of the attributed text for the `.highlighted` state.

When the user highlights the button, I want the background that shows around the title to have the same frame as the button.

I've tried positive and negative values for the button's `titleEdgeInsets` and `contentEdgeInsets` with no luck. Any suggestions here? Thanks

Comment: Well I had an answer but you totally changed the question into something I find incomprehensible.

Comment: Well I'm just hoping to get you to clarify the question. That's not combative; the aim was so I could try to help.

Comment: I understand and let me also say I greatly appreciate the time you put into answering questions on SO. I was more speaking to a question I answered last week where the comments as well as the answer all had a pretty combative tone. It also applies to questions I've asked in the past

Comment: If you're talking about your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672144/how-do-i-get-a-uibutton-to-size-itself-in-a-uistackview exactly the opposite is true; I spent a lot of time on that question (a couple of hours actually), writing example code that proved that the code you had supplied did not have the effect you described and, unlike your code, was a complete and reproducible example. Your response was basically to reveal that I had wasted my time because in fact your code was different than what you had showed. At that point I wasn't rude, I just walked away.

Comment: Yeah that was the main one I was referencing. I was trying to obfuscate the code so as not to copy and paste code directly and I did a bad job there. It was never my intent to waste your time, quite the contrary. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (meaning most controllable) way in my opinion is to use a button subclass and override `titleRect`. It's called when highlighted and when unhighlighted so you get a chance to change your answer depending on the state.

However, that won't change the size of the background color of attributed text, because it applies only to the text. You'd need to change the background color of the title label itself.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I appreciate your help.